# Repository Pattern implementation WITH EF relational tables

Tags: entity-framework, repository

I have 4 tables 
`Student`, `Result`, `ResultDetail` and `Queue`

`Result` and `ResultDetails` are related with `ResultID` as ForeignKey. 
`Student` and `Result` are related with  `StudentID` as ForeignKey
and `Student` can have 'N' number of results but will have only one active `Result`.
`Queue` and `Student` are related with  `StudentID`.

Now using Entity Framework and Repository Pattern,
I want to 
Perform ->

```
Queue q join Student  s on q.StudentID = s.StudentID
join Result r on q.StudentId = r.StudentID
Join ResultDetail  rd on t.ResultID = rd.ResultId where r.IsActive = 1
```

Could some one please help in achieving this with Repository Pattern?
Do we need to create 4 Repositories even though we have relations between tables.
Performance is also a criteria .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could some one please help in achieving this with Repository Pattern?

Yes.  Create a custom subtype of DbContext to serve as your Repository.  Add a DbSet Property for each of your entity types.  Also put Navigation Properties on your Entities so your query so you don't have to use `join` in LINQ.

Comment: Thanks Dave.Thats helps. I am struggling how can i achieve joins with Navigation Properties especially with multiple tables Nested Like Queue, Student ,Result and ResultDetails

Comment: Add your entity definitions and EF DbContext to the question, and indicate where you are struggling.  Also tag the question what version of EF and what database you are targeting.

Comment: did litle bit more research on using "include" after setting Navigation properties and that helped in improving the performance. Thank you !!